# Implementing comparator in constructor when PriorityQueue is nested

Tags: java, comparator, priority-queue

I want to make the following:

```
ArrayList of PriorityQueue of Integer[](  
ArrayList<PrirorityQueue<Integer[]>> )
```

But I am unable to implement Comparator in the constructor area.

```
ArrayList<PriorityQueue<Integer[]>> p = new ArrayList<>
((o1,o2) -> o1[2] - o2[2]);
```

I was trying to make an ArrayList of PriorityQueue which contains integer array based on the third index of the integer array. [image]

Comment: The `ArrayList` never constructs `PriorityQueue` objects for you. You need to pass the comparator to the `PriorityQueue` constructor every time you create a new `PriorityQueue` object.

Comment: Why do you use `ArrayList` here? Seems just using `PriorityQueue` is fine.  `PriorityQueue<Integer[]> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>((o1,o2) -> o1[2] - o2[2]);`